# Do i need separate index in addition to primary key in a MySQL table?

Tags: mysql, sql, database, sqlite

My Table Schema is

> CREATE TABLE ITEMS(Time , Name, Token) PRIMARY_KEY(Time, NAME).

Where Time is the timestamp the item is created. When i do the following query

> SELECT Name, Token from ITEMS where name = `shoes`

it takes a while to load the data as my table has more than million rows.

Should i need to add `INDEX` for faster retrieval of data? I already have an `INDEX` for this table as there is a `PRIMARY KEY`.

Comment: Primary keys are already index. You may consider adding an index to Token.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need a separate index for `name`.  The primary key index can handle name, but only in conjunction with `time`.

If you defined it instead as:

```
 PRIMARY_KEY(Name, Time)
```

Then your query could take advantage of the index.

MySQL has pretty good documentation on composite indexes [here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/multiple-column-indexes.html).

Answer (score 0):

When you create index using `PRIMARY_KEY(Time, NAME)`, these values will be concatenated. There is no way for MySQL to use this index to search by NAME.

BTW, you may get lot of useful hints from query optimiser if you use EXPLAN keyword in front of your query like this:

```
EXPLAIN SELECT Name, Token from ITEMS where name = shoes
```

Keep your eye on output marked "where". This tells how many records MySQL needs to fetch and examine manually after all indexes are exhausted. No need to wait or test in blind.